# cannot initialize std::unique_ptr class member

Tags: c++

I have the following code

Parser.hh

```
namespace Essembly {
...
public:
    Parser();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<FactoryExpr> factory;
    ...
}
```

Parser.cc

```
namespace Essembly {
Parser::Parser(): factory(std::make_unique<FactoryExpr>()) { }
}
```

and this is the factory
FactoryExpr.hh

```
namespace Essembly {
    class FactoryExpr {
    public:
         FactoryExpr();
         ~FactoryExpr();
    }
}
```

FactoryExpr.cc

```
namespace Essembly {
   FactoryExpr::FactoryExpr(){ }
   FactoryExpr::~FactoryExpr() { }

}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error

```
std::__1::unique_ptr<FactoryExpr> Essembly::Parser::factory
no instance of constructor "std::__1::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr [with _Tp=FactoryExpr, _Dp=std::__1::default_delete<FactoryExpr>]" matches the argument listC/C++(289)
parser.cc(9, 26): argument types are: (std::__1::unique_ptr<Essembly::FactoryExpr, std::__1::default_delete<Essembly::FactoryExpr>>)
```

I browsed on SO and the MICROSOFT docs, and I think I am doing this correctly. Could someone spot the mistake.

Comment: The FactoryExpr constructor is private.

Comment: no it's public. I forgot to write it here

Comment: Works [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1d55d60d6324b66), so somehow your real code is different from the posted code (which does have typos).

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/PrevP71jY (removed some typos from your original question)